# Best way validate object in c# with "Manager" class

Tags: c#, .net-core, abp

In my project I have an class named Precatorio

```
public class Precatorio : Pesquisa.Pesquisa
{ 
    public int FornecedorId { get; set; }
    public Fornecedor Fornecedor { get; set; }
    public int FundoId { get; set; }
    public Fundo Fundo { get; set; }
    public int DestinacaoRecursoId { get; set; }
    public DestinacaoRecurso DestinacaoRecurso { get; set; }
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }
    public int Natureza { get; set; }
    public long Tipo { get; set; }
    public decimal Valor { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    private Precatorio()
    { 
    }

    internal Precatorio(
        int fornecedorId,
        Fornecedor fornecedor,
        int fundoId,
        Fundo fundo,
        int destinacaoRecursoId,
        DestinacaoRecurso destinacaoRecurso,
        DateTime data,
        int natureza,
        long tipo,
        decimal valor,
        string descricao
    )
    {   
        FornecedorId = fornecedorId;
        Fornecedor = fornecedor;
        FundoId = fundoId;
        Fundo = fundo;
        DestinacaoRecursoId = destinacaoRecursoId;
        DestinacaoRecurso = destinacaoRecurso;
        Data = data;
        Natureza = natureza;
        Tipo = tipo;
        Valor = valor;
        Descricao = descricao;
    }
}
```

And a PrecatorioManager class which validates the fields in order to return an object

```
public class PrecatorioManager : DomainService
{

    private readonly IPrecatorioRepository _precatorioRepository;

    public PrecatorioManager(IPrecatorioRepository precatorioRepository)
    {
        _precatorioRepository = precatorioRepository;
    }

    public async Task<Precatorio> CreateAsync(
        int fornecedorId,
        Fornecedor fornecedor,
        int fundoId,
        Fundo fundo,
        int destinacaoRecursoId,
        DestinacaoRecurso destinacaoRecurso,
        DateTime data,
        int natureza,
        long tipo,
        decimal valor,
        string descricao

    )
    {
        return new Precatorio(
            fornecedorId,
            fornecedor,
            fundoId,
            fundo,
            destinacaoRecursoId,
            destinacaoRecurso,
            data,
            natureza,
            tipo,
            valor,
            descricao
        );
    }

}
```

The problem is that PrecatorioManager.CreateAsync require to many fields, and it will be too much difficult to change some field and refactor in all the code that use this method. Second problem is that sometimes a developer may not use the PrecatorioManager.CreateAsync and pass throw de validation.Validations needs to pass in PrecatorioManager  because some validations require repository injection and will be needed in all cases. Developers commonly use just:

```
var NewPrecatorio = ObjectMapper.Map<CreateUpdatePrecatorioDto,Precatorio>(input);
```

So, I'm looking for a way that internal Precatorio calls PrecatorioManager.CreateAsync or a best solution.

Comment: You need a Factory class that create your Predicatorio and if your class needs 10 parameters, you need 10 parameters. If you allow create a Predicatorio instance outside your Factory class, you can't force to pass your validation. May be possible use less parameters and allow change the others outside if there are lots properties outside your validation.

Comment: For the first problem, you'll have to consider how data should be organized in your domain.  For example, do `fornecedor` and `fornecedorId` often get passed around together? Maybe `FornecedorId` should be a property on the `Fornecedor` class, or maybe you need another generic class to represent this combination of a model object and its ID. It might also make sense to use a `record` class with a primary constructor to reduce the repetition of the parameters, properties, and mappings.

Comment: For the second problem, if it's _really_ a problem, you could put the `Precatorio` class and its manager into a separate assembly so its internal constructor cannot be invoked by developers working in other parts of the code. You could mark the constructor Obsolete, or you could even write a custom Roslyn analyzer to produce a warning or error when people write code to invoke that constructor. But that might all be overkill, depending on how closely you work with the other developers and how likely and how serious a problem it would be to create an unvalidated precatorio.

Comment: Another pattern I've seen is to have another class, like a `ValidPrecatorio`, which is required by your other domain models, just as a kind of hint to developers that they should have run a Precatorio through a validation method to create this object before they pass it in as an argument. A `ValidPrecatorio` would just have a single `Value` property with the actual `Precatorio` on it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this belongs in codereview stackexchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, the `PrecatorioManager` class is responsible for validating new `Precatorio` objects and you have three design objectives:

1. The only way to create a `Precatorio` object is to call `PrecatorioManager.CreateAsync()` to obtain one.
2. The developer must not be allowed to bypass the validation of `Precatorio`.
3. The pass-through initializer must be robust and expandable for the future when additional properties may be added to the `Precatorio` class.

Similar to the other answer so far, this `Precatorio` has a `private` constructor that prevents direct instantiation. The static `Create` method has `internal` visibility to give access to `PrecatorioManager`, but checks the [[CallerMemberName]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute?view=net-6.0) attribute and provides "some" assurance by throwing an exception if not being called from a method named `CreateAsync`.

One possibility for simplifying the arguments `PrecatorioManager.CreateAsync()` would be using a [CollectionInitializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers) similar to the way many HTTP requests are formed.

```
internal static Precatorio? Create(
    Dictionary<string, object> initializer, 
    [CallerMemberName] string? caller = null)
{
    if (caller == "CreateAsync")
    {
        var created = new Precatorio();
        foreach (var kvp in initializer)
        {
            PropertyInfo? pi = typeof(Precatorio).GetProperty(kvp.Key);
            if (pi == null)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(
                    false,
                    $"Expecting a property named {kvp}");
            }
            else
            {
                pi.SetValue(created, kvp.Value);
            }
        }
        return created;
    }
    else throw new InvalidOperationException(
        $"Precatorio.Create cannot be called from {caller}."); 
}
```

The `PrecatorioManager` class is now greatly simplified:

```
internal class PrecatorioManager
{
    private PrecatorioRepository precatorioRepository;
    public PrecatorioManager(PrecatorioRepository precatorioRepository) =>
        this.precatorioRepository = precatorioRepository;
    internal async Task<Precatorio?> CreateAsync(Dictionary<string, object> init)
    {
        var created = Precatorio.Create(init);
        await ValidateAsync(created);
        return created;
    }
    private async Task<bool> ValidateAsync(Precatorio? created)
    {
        if(created == null) return false;

        Console.WriteLine("VALIDATING!");
        await Task.Delay(100); // It's up to you what is being awaited here.

        return true; // For example, return pass/fail result
    }
}
```

**TESTBENCH**

Attempting to instantiate `Precatorio` won't even compile:

```
// Illegal attempt to instantiate Precatorio();
var doesNotCompile = new Precatorio();
```

And attempting to bypass the validation would result in an exception being thrown:

```
// Illegal attempt to create Precatorio directly
try
{
    var notAllowed = await Precatorio.Create(
        initializer: new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "FornecedorId", 123 },
            { "FundoId", 456 },
            { "DestinacaoRecursoId", 798},
            { "Data", DateTime.UtcNow },
            { "Tipo", 0xeeeeffff },
            { "Valor", 1.234m },
            { "Descricao", "This is a test" },
        });
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{ex.Message}{Environment.NewLine}");
}
```

A properly formed call *will* succeed. Console message confirms  validation has taken place:

```
// Normal create through manager
var precatorio = await manager.CreateAsync(
    init: new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "FornecedorId", 123 },
        { "FundoId", 456 },
        { "DestinacaoRecursoId", 798},
        { "Data", DateTime.UtcNow },
        { "Tipo", 0xeeeeffff },
        { "Valor", 1.234m },
        { "Descricao", "This is a test" },
    });

Console.WriteLine(precatorio?.ToString());
```

The console printout from the instantiation of a validated `Precatorio` object:

[image: console output]

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/precatorio-net6.git) this testbench.

Comment: Great answer! In Company developers just use:
var NewPrecatorio = ObjectMapper.Map<CreateUpdatePrecatorioDto,Precatorio>(input); 
Which auto use the internal Precatorio for instantiation. I'm thinking about put all properties inside PrecatorioManager, make an AutoMapper, then create a method inside PrecatorioManager that receives PrecatorioManager and returns a new Precatorio if valid. What do you think about?

Comment: I agree that sounds like a good approach. I'm using `Reflection` in a somewhat manual way whereas `AutoMapper` uses `Reflection` but wraps it and ties it in a bow! Sounds like we're all on the same page though.

Comment: Ooh!  I like this answer a lot, but as I understand it, it seems to fail to enforce the mandatory presence of all of the required parameters, and also allows the consuming developer to pass an invalid key-value pair, eg, `{ "FornecedorId", “one hundred and twenty three” }` without a compile time error.

CallerMemberName is really neat, TIL. :)

Comment: Oh I agree for sure!! My thinking on that is, well, we're calling a `Validation` method and it could do things like count the properties and fail if there were a mismatch. Or it could make a `List<PropertyInfo>` of the public properties and remove each as it was identified which means any properties still in the list could be **reported**  so developer could fix the initializer. Definitely this answer leans on the `Validate` heavily.

Comment: An alternative would be a strongly typed `PrecatorioInitializer` class that would still pass through easily. For example, I see this approach used a lot in the C# wrapper for GoogleDrive API.

Comment: @IVSoftware I discover deloper can still bypass validation on update with like:

var aporte = await _aporteRepository.GetAsync(id);
aporte = ObjectMapper.Map(input, aporte);
await _aporteRepository.UpdateAsync(aporte);

Comment: @IVSoftware I refined my question and create another one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72890951/how-to-prevent-automapper-from-mapping-a-class

Comment: I appreciate that feedback. The problem we face is that developers can abuse `Reflection` to instantiate even private members of an Assembly. It seems to me that if someone is determined enough, they would be difficult to thwart! Perhaps it's more about making sure that it's hard enough to accomplish that they don't do it accidentally. Can we stop someone from doing it with forethought and malice? I'm not sure. I'll have a look at your new question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Change the object's constructor to private and use a public static method to generate objects.  Now, short of arcane magic, the consuming developer cannot construct a `Precatorio` without going through validation. As (another) Victor mentions in his comment, if you need ten parameters, you need ten parameters.

```
public class Precatorio : Pesquisa.Pesquisa
{ 
    public int FornecedorId { get; set; }
    public Fornecedor Fornecedor { get; set; }
    public int FundoId { get; set; }
    public Fundo Fundo { get; set; }
    public int DestinacaoRecursoId { get; set; }
    public DestinacaoRecurso DestinacaoRecurso { get; set; }
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }
    public int Natureza { get; set; }
    public long Tipo { get; set; }
    public decimal Valor { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

private Precatorio(PrecatorioManager precatorioManager)
{ 
}

private Precatorio(
    int fornecedorId,
    Fornecedor fornecedor,
    int fundoId,
    Fundo fundo,
    int destinacaoRecursoId,
    DestinacaoRecurso destinacaoRecurso,
    DateTime data,
    int natureza,
    long tipo,
    decimal valor,
    string descricao)    
{   
    FornecedorId = fornecedorId;
    Fornecedor = fornecedor;
    FundoId = fundoId;
    Fundo = fundo;
    DestinacaoRecursoId = destinacaoRecursoId;
    DestinacaoRecurso = destinacaoRecurso;
    Data = data;
    Natureza = natureza;
    Tipo = tipo;
    Valor = valor;
    Descricao = descricao;
}

public static async Task<Precatorio> CreateAsync(
    int fornecedorId,
    Fornecedor fornecedor,
    int fundoId,
    Fundo fundo,
    int destinacaoRecursoId,
    DestinacaoRecurso destinacaoRecurso,
    DateTime data,
    int natureza,
    long tipo,
    decimal valor,
    string descricao)
  {
    return new Precatorio(
        fornecedorId,
        fornecedor,
        fundoId,
        fundo,
        destinacaoRecursoId,
        destinacaoRecurso,
        data,
        natureza,
        tipo,
        valor,
        descricao
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: CreateAsync still have many properties and I can't inject repository inside domain entity. By the way, thank you for your answer.